# WPF UI doesn't update textblock in controltemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate, textblock

I made a sample XAML and C# for WPF below:

XAML :

```
<Button Name="btn">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Name="textblock1" Text="sampletext1" />
            <Grid>
        <ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

C# :

```
Grid grid = btn.Template.LoadContent() as Grid;
var textblock = grid.FindName("textblock1") as TextBlock;
textblock.Text = "sampletext2";
```

I was able to retrieve and change the textblock text in code behind but it seems that the UI doesn't update it. May I know how to solve this?

Comment: @ASh should be "sampletext2". I just edited

Comment: Why are you using a control template inside a button to display a `TextBlock`?

Comment: @MichalCiechan I'm actually making an image and words to form an image button in WPF. but the words will changed depends on the users' action.

Comment: Why not use a binding from inside the template?

Comment: Also you know Button.Content can contain any arbitrary content? not just text?

Comment: @MichalCiechan or maybe u can provide some examples? im kinda new towards wpf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code in any of the events

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainWindow_Loaded;

        }

        void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBlock textBlockInTemplate = (TextBlock)btn.Template.FindName("textblock1", btn);
            textBlockInTemplate.Text = "SampleText2";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, been stuck here since last few hours. After hours of research, i finally know what control template is. Dont know it would be this easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes a copy of the value of the text block then assign a property named "Text" to the copy's value. You never actually change the text inside the button. Your text block is called textblock1, textblock was initialized from textblock1 but once that is done they aren't linked together.

It's been awhile since i've used WPF but you need to re-assign the text value to the button using something like this :

```
textblock1.Text = textblock;
```

or even simpler:

```
textblock1.Text = "sampletext2";
```

Comment: the textbox is bind in the controltemplate so your solution was unable to change or read the text from the textbox.